# Apple Mail baseline issue

Tags: email

When I design an html email blast, I always have a problem with the way text renders in Apple Mail. It's always on a lower baseline than the way it renders anywhere else. Is there a way to override that without affecting how it's viewed elsewhere? P.S. I'm using Mac OSX 10.6.8.